# IIS URLRewrite Regular Expression

Tags: regex, iis, redirect, url-rewriting

I am horrible with regular expressions and new to the URL Rewrite module in IIS so please bear with me...

I have a scenario where I have 1-2 pages that I need to be redirected to a specific location and protocol (https).

Desired URL

```
https://www.domain.com/specific/location/mypage.aspx
```

I need to make sure users are hitting this specific url when trying to access this page. So any of the below should redirect the user to my "desired" url:

```
http://www.domain.com/specific/location/mypage.aspx
http://domain.com/specific/location/mypage.aspx
https://domain.com/specific/location/mypage.aspx
http://www.anotherDomain.com/specific/location/mypage.aspx
http://anotherDomain.com.com/specific/location/mypage.aspx
https://anotherDomain.com.com/specific/location/mypage.aspx
```

I need this to happen for this page and one other page and I need to make sure only these pages are being redirected to ssl, so the rest of the site should be redirected to its http version if the user types in https. How can I accomplish this, do I need more than one rule, etc?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully, this isn't as complicated as it looks. When creating rules using the IIS URL Rewrite module, the "url" in the match tag is only looking at everything after the host name. It doesn't see the domain.com.

So, in your web.config, within the system.webserver section, in your rewrite section:

```
<rule name="Redirect Specific Location" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="specific\/location\/mypage\.aspx"/>
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain.com/specific/location/mypage.aspx"/>
</rule>
```

That way any URL coming in that ends with specific/location/mypage.aspx will be redirected, no matter what the hostname is.